# create an output for weekend in datepicker PHP

Tags: javascript, php

hello and greetings to all. i would like some help with my code. i'm currently creating a date-picker for my project. i would like to have an output value from the selected day if it is certain event such as weekend or holiday.

this is the script that i want to keep in my code.:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#checkout").datepicker();
        $("#checkin").datepicker({
            minDate : new Date(),
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                var date = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);
                $("#checkout").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

for the html.:

```
<form name="form" action="checkroom.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm(this);">
    <div class="row">        
        <div class="large-6 columns" style="max-width:100%;">
            <label class="fontcolor" for="checkin">Check In
                <input name="checkin" id="checkin" style="width:100%;"/>
            </label>
        </div>            
        <div class="large-6 columns" style="max-width:100%;">
            <label class="fontcolor" for="checkout">Check Out
                <input name="checkout" id="checkout" style="width:100%;"/>
            </label>                       
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

trying to get an idea from this.:

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    $inputDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $date, new 
    DateTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam"));
    return $inputDate->format('N') >= 6;
}
```

and

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    $inputDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $date, new 
    DateTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam"));
    return $inputDate->format('N') >= 6;
}
```

and

```
$("#TxtStrtDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var day = date.getUTCDay();
        if (day == '6') {
            alert('its a saturday');
        }
    }
});
```

I have try a lot but cant get the result. 
I would like to ask a help how to combine the script and how to make it work.the result that I want is.

[click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAZzH.png)

from the picked date i will create a value

```
$result = weekend
$status = $selecteddate
if($result = $status) {
    echo "WEEKEND";
}
else {
    echo "urghhh,still workday";
}
```

thanks for the help.
best regards
Fzstyle

based on answer below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkout").datepicker();
  $("#checkin").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var date = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, 
      dateText);
      var daynumber = date.getDay();
      if(daynumber === 0 || daynumber === 6) {
        $("#weekend_notifier").text("Its weekend");
      }
      $("#checkout").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
    }
  });
});
```

html.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form name="form" action="checkroom.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm(this);">
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-6 columns" style="max-width:100%;">
     <label class="fontcolor" for="checkin">Check In
     <input name="checkin" id="checkin" style="width:100%;"/>
     </label>
     <span id="weekend_notifier"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="large-6 columns" style="max-width:100%;">
     <label class="fontcolor" for="checkout">Check Out
       <input name="checkout" id="checkout" style="width:100%;"/>
     </label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

how to call out the "its weekend" to others page?

for example

```
<?php
include ("html.php")
$("#weekend_notifier") = $weekend;
echo "$weekend";
?>
```

thanks.

Comment: @RPelzer tq for the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for weekend, for holidays you would have to define what you consider as a holiday.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkout").datepicker();
  $("#checkin").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var date = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);
      var daynumber = date.getDay();
      if(daynumber === 0 || daynumber === 6) {
        $("#weekend_notifier").text("Its weekend");
      }
      $("#checkout").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form name="form" action="checkroom.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm(this);">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="large-6 columns" style="max-width:100%;">
      <label class="fontcolor" for="checkin">Check In
        <input name="checkin" id="checkin" style="width:100%;"/>
      </label>
      <span id="weekend_notifier"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="large-6 columns" style="max-width:100%;">
      <label class="fontcolor" for="checkout">Check Out
        <input name="checkout" id="checkout" style="width:100%;"/>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.. that help me a lot. but if i want the value of "its weekend" can be call out in another page instead of prompt the user that the selected date is weekend. you can refer to the edited post